# How to convert a list with sublists to a set with corresponding subset in python?

Tags: python-3.x

For example, I have a list:

```
l = [["apple","banana","pear"],["pen","apple"]]
```

And I want to convert it to a set,which is

```
{{"apple","banana","pear"},{"pen","apple"}}
```

What command should I use?

Answer (score 0):

<s>This one:</s>

```
l = set(set(x) for x in l)
```

Set is unhashable so it is not possible if type `set` is required. But unchangeable set implementations may be hashable as long as they provides `__hash__` method.

Comment: This does not work because sets are unhashable types.  This question is a little trickier than that.

Comment: This command doesn't work since I have sublist in the list. It will return an error:TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'. Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, because sets are unhashable objects. This means you cannot put sets into sets. You can however turn the list of lists into a list of sets with `list(map(set,l))`.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to get what you are trying to do. Is to create a set of tuples that were once sets. You cant have a set of sets because sets are not hashable.

```
l=set([tuple(set(sublist)) for sublist in l])
```

Answer (score 0):

Sets are not hashable, but frozensets are:

```
l = set(frozenset(x) for x in l)
```